# Onclick with argument causes javascript syntax error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, openlayers-3

I got the "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier" when clicking element that goes by id "elem". Can you please tell me how to fix this ?

```
formulaireDB.allDocs({
    include_docs: true
}).then(function(result) {

    for (x in result.rows) {
        docFeature = result.rows[x].doc;
        coord_nv = [docFeature.geometry.coordinates[0], 
                    docFeature.geometry.coordinates[1]];
         position = to3857(coord_nv);

        map.addOverlay(new ol.Overlay({
            position: ol.proj.transform(
                [docFeature.geometry.coordinates[0],
                docFeature.geometry.coordinates[1]],
                'EPSG:4326',
                'EPSG:3857'),
                 element: $('<img id="elem" onclick="clickmarker(' 
                           + result + ',' + x  + ')" src="./img/pin32.png">')
        }));
    }
}).catch(function(err) {
    console.log(err);
});

}

function clickmarker(rt, ind) {
    var res = rt.rows[ind].doc.geometry.coordinates;
    console.log(res);
}
```

Comment: you might catch the errors more if you formatted your code a bit better, instead of passing so many things into the constructor create variables to represent them and then pass them it.  It will make your life and alot of other developers lives easier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are concatenating `result` to a string and loses its value as an object in this line:

```
element: $('<img id="elem" onclick="clickmarker(' + result + ',' + x  + ')" src="./img/pin32.png">')
```

You may need to add the click listener after it's been created rather than in-line.

Something such as

```
element: $('<img...>').on('click',function(){ clickmarker(result,x); });
```

Comment: Thank you ! That pretty much solved the issue, but it has to be on a separate line `$("#elem").on('click',function(){ clickmarker(result,x); });`

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra brace after your catch function. try this:

```js
formulaireDB.allDocs({
  include_docs: true
}).then(function(result) {


  for (x in result.rows) {
    docFeature = result.rows[x].doc;
    coord_nv = [docFeature.geometry.coordinates[0], docFeature.geometry.coordinates[1]];
    position = to3857(coord_nv);
    // add marker

    map.addOverlay(new ol.Overlay({
      position: ol.proj.transform(
        [docFeature.geometry.coordinates[0], docFeature.geometry.coordinates[1]],
        'EPSG:4326',
        'EPSG:3857'
      ),
      element: $('<img id="elem" onclick="clickmarker(' + result + ',' + x + ')" src="./img/pin32.png">')
    }));



  }
}).catch(function(err) {
  console.log(err);
});



function clickmarker(rt, ind) {
  var res = rt.rows[ind].doc.geometry.coordinates;
  console.log(res);
}
```

Comment: It's missing one line at the beginning, my bad: `function ShowFormulaires(){
...
}
` ends right after the catch part